# How to check if my OwnerId exists on the List Custom settings in apex

Tags: apex, customsetting

I have a List custom setting as ReferrerUpdateExempt__c which has one field UserID__c
i have a list of UserIds in this setting. I want to check in a trigger if a new Opportunity owner exists in this List of UserIds.

I tried using as below but i got the Key as Name of the ID but not ID itself:

```
Map<String,ReferrerUpdateExempt__c> RefupdtExmpt = ReferrerUpdateExempt__c.getAll();
if((newOpp.OwnerId != oldOpp.OwnerId && !**RefupdtExmpt.contains(newOpp.OwnerId)**)|| Test.isRunningTest()){
```

Can any one please correct me to check against that list?

Answer (score 1):

You should really use a `Hierarchy Custom Settings` for this functionality. If you store the value in a String field, you are going to run into case sensitivity issues. `Hierarchy Custom Settings` actually create a lookup relationship.

Determining whether there is a custom setting record for a `User` will then be straightforward:

```
Boolean isExempt = Exemption_Setting__c.getValues(myOwnerId) != null;
```

If you want to use the setting for multiple exemptions, you can add a checkbox field, e.g. `Referrer_Exempt__c`. If you set the `Org Wide Default` for this checkbox to false, then the following code will help you get what you need:

```
Boolean isExempt = Exemption_Setting__c.getInstance(myOwnerId).Referrer_Exempt__c;
```

Comment: Case sensitivity shouldn't be an issue (because normally you'd be checking 18 character IDs), but +1 for the correct solution.

Comment: @sfdcfox, normally *you* would use the case insensitive Id. But admins aren't to be trusted! :) Regardless, might as well take advantage of static types.

Comment: To be pedantic, comparing an Id to a String promotes both to Id values. Consider this assertion... `System.assert(Id.valueOf(UserInfo.getUserId()) == String.valueOf(UserInfo.getUserId()).left(15));` So, as long as the Id value in the text field were a 15 or 18 character Id, and the other value is an Id (such as it would in a lookup field), then the result should be consistent. As an aside, `UserInfo.getUserId()` apparently returns a String...

Comment: That's really surprising about `UserInfo.getUserId()`. I'm not sure the type coercion argument comes into play here, though, because the issue is the `Set.contains` method, not `==` comparison. Calling that with a `Set<String>` means you need to know the length and case to be expected. I would think calling `Set<String>.contains(Id)` would use the 18 character Id.